# Passing input variables from Custom pages to Sections in NSIS

Tags: nsis

Below is a program that I wrote which utilizes the given IpConfig function from the wiki. I am trying to have the user input the name of the text file ($Text) then have that text file be populated with the ipconfig information for the computer. This can easily be done on the command prompt but my goal is to hopefully get it working on NSIS. I was able to dump all the data acquired from the detailprints by using DumpLog. This function produces the .txt file I need. I am struggling with having the user set the name of this .txt file.

The issue I have is that the program ends after the first custom page. I can input the name of the file but then have to hit close and the program aborts. I have tried creating a CustomLeave page but could not integrate the ipconfig function with it.

Unfortunately even after further restructuring I can create the text file without a name that is fully populated with the needed data, which tells me an empty "Text" name variable is being passed.

Your help is appreciated! thank you.

```
!addplugindir "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\x86-unicode"
!addplugindir "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\x86-ansi"
!addplugindir "${NSISDIR}\Plugins"

!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "winMessages.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"

!Macro ShowResult ItemString
    Pop $0 
    Pop $1
    ${if} $0 == "ok"
        DetailPrint "${ItemString} $1"
    ${Else}
        DetailPrint "${ItemString} Error: $1"
    ${EndIf}
!MacroEnd

!Macro ShowMultiResult ItemString
    Pop $0 
    Pop $1
    ${if} $0 != "ok"
        DetailPrint "${ItemString} Error: $1"
    ${EndIf}
!MacroEnd


    ;!define LVM_GETITEMCOUNT 0x1004
    ;!define LVM_GETITEMTEXT 0x102D

!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "Some location.bmp" 
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English" 

OutFile "something.exe"


Page custom custompage
Var dialog
Var Label
Var Text
Var TextBox


Function custompage 
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Something" "Tool" 

        nsDialogs::Create 1018
            Pop $dialog

        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "enter text name"
            Pop $Label

        ${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 93% 12u $Text
            Pop $TextBox

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd



Section

    DetailPrint "Windows IP-configuration"
    DetailPrint ""
    IpConfig::GetHostName
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     Host Name.......................:"
    IpConfig::GetPrimaryDNSSuffix
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     Primary DNS Suffix..............:"
    IpConfig::GetNodeType
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     Node Type.......................:"
    IpConfig::IsIPRoutingEnabled
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     IP Routing Enabled..............:"
    IpConfig::IsWINSProxyEnabled
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     WINS Proxy Enabled..............:"
    IpConfig::GetDNSSuffixSearchList
    !InsertMacro ShowResult "     DNS Suffix Search List..........:"
    DetailPrint ""
    GetFunctionAddress $2 EnabledAdaptersCallback
    IpConfig::GetEnabledNetworkAdaptersIDsCB $2
    !InsertMacro ShowMultiResult "     GetEnabledNetworkAdaptersIDs:"


    StrCpy $0 "$Desktop\$Text.txt"
    Push $0
    Call DumpLog


SectionEnd
```

Copied functions below for DumpLog and IPConfig - Deleted for clarity.   ========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, putting all those `!addplugindir` instructions at the start of your script is not a good idea, if you call the wrong plug-in type the installer will crash!

Your installer ends after the first page because you only have one page!

Using DumpLog seems like pointless work, you can just write to the file directly if you want to.

```
OutFile test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user

!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"


!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom custompage custompageleave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Var ConfigFile
Var TextBox

Function .onInit
StrCpy $ConfigFile "Text.txt" ; Set default
FunctionEnd

Function custompage 
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Something" "Tool" 

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "enter text name"
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 93% 12u $ConfigFile
    Pop $TextBox

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function custompageleave
${NSD_GetText} $TextBox $ConfigFile
FunctionEnd


Section
    FileOpen $5 "$Desktop\$ConfigFile" w ; Forcing $Desktop is a bit weird, user should be able to choose a full path?
    FileWrite $5 "Hello$\r$\n"
    FileWrite $5 "World$\r$\n"
    FileClose $5
SectionEnd
```

Using DumpLog is fine if you want to display the output and also save it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was only forcing $Desktop for self testing. I have edited my code and incorporated your comments and now it works perfectly. Appreciate it